# Limit of series - exponential series

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Series nd continuous functions
Question :
 For $0<x<\infty ,$ let $$f(x) = \sum_{0}^{\infty } e^{-nx}$$ .Show that f(x) is continuous function.
Work Done:
 I know every concept of sequences and series and how to find their convergence and divergence. But if we will find taylor's expansion of $ e^{-nx}$ and put it in our question,then we will get something like $\sum \sum$  .

I dont know how to solve quantities like these.How will we solve this now??And i cant make out how the continuity of the function is related to a series. Is it if we prove the series convergent for every given x , then the function is continuous because the series is convergent?? if this is so, how can we relate the convergence of a series to the continuity of a function??. Can you help me understand the basic concept involved here??. Kindly help me to relate the convergence of a series to the continuity. thanks a lot in advance......

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sum y^n=\frac{1}{1-y}$ for $-1<y<1$.

Answer (score 0):

A function is continous if it's the *uniform* limit of continous functions. Your series doesn't converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, but it *does* converge uniformly on $(a,\infty)$ for $a > 0$.

If you can show that, you're done, because for each $x > 0$ you can then pick an $0 < a < x$, and since $f$ is then continous on $(a,\infty) \ni x$ it's in particular continous at $x$.